Unexpected output when testing for largest input number
a = input("Enter the first number:")
b = input("Enter the second number:")
c = input("Enter the third number:")
if (a> b and a> c ):
    print(a,"is the greatest number")
elif (b>c): 
    print(b,"is the greatest number")
else:
    print(c,"is the greatest number")

If I run the code, input 33 for the first two numbers and 6 for the last, I get 6 which is wrong. Please correct me where the problem is.
I expected 33 but got 6. I tried with a>=b and a>=c,b>=c. Yet the output is 6 which is wrong.

"6" is indeed greater than "33" - in alphabetical order.  You're dealing entirely with strings here, not numbers - you'd need to apply int() to the user's input.

Oh, thanks, I totally forget about that.

You are getting input as strings and comparing your data as such. This does a lexicographic compare where "6" is indeed "greater than" "33".
To correct, convert your data to ints.
a = int(input("Enter the first number:"))
b = int(input("Enter the second number:"))
c = int(input("Enter the third number:"))

Once you learn about lists you will be able to significantly streamline this. E.g.
vals_count = 3
vals = [
  int(input(f"Enter number #{i}: ")) 
  for i in range(1, vals_count+1)
]
print(f"{max(vals)} is the greatest number.")


you could create another varible for holding the highest number, then just run input by input so if a>b then a=highest_number,if not b=highest_number, then if c>highest_number then c=highest_number, if not then highest_number remains unchanged so when you print highest_number it will print the highest number that was entered and stored in the varible highest_number.

#largest number program.
largest_number = -999999999
Input the first value.
number = int(input("Enter a number or type -1 to stop: "))
If the number is not equal to -1, continue.
while number != -1:
# Is number larger than largest_number?
if number > largest_number:
# Yes, update largest_number.
largest_number = number
# Input the next number.
number = int(input("Enter a number or type -1 to stop: "))
Print the largest number.
print("The largest number is:", largest_number)

This needs work on formatting, and it doesn't address the actual problem the OP is having.
